# The Best overloaded method has some invalid arguments using Asp.net MVc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am creating a simple invententy system in Asp.net Mvc i got the Error as 
**The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.Dbset.Add(WebApplication27.Models.sale)' has some invalid arguments**

i got the eror on this line of the project **db.sales.Add(sale);** i am tring to solve this problem since yesterday but couldn't do it.

**sales.class file**
    **

```
public partial class sale
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> subtotal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> pay { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> balance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**

Sales Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveNew(string data)
{
    ajaxModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ajaxModel>(data);
    bool status = false;
    try
    {
        using (aspposEntities1 db = new aspposEntities1())
        {
            //insert into Sales table
            var sale = new sale
            {


                subtotal = model.total,
                pay = model.pay,
                balance = model.balance

            };

          db.sales.Add(sale);



            **db.SaveChanges();**  // Error this line


            model.data.ForEach( m =>
            {
                //get the product and deduct the subtotal
                int db_product = db.products.First(e => e.id== m.barcode_id);
                db_product.qty = db_product.qty - m.qty;

                db.sales_product.Add(new sales_product
                {
               //     sales_id = sale.id,
                    barcode_id = m.barcode_id,
                    price = m.pro_price,
                    qty = m.qty,
                    total = m.total_cost
                });
            });
            db.SaveChanges();

        //    model.orderid = sale.id;
            status = true;
        }
        TempData["Data"] = model;
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status, message = "Entry saved successfully" } };
        //return RedirectToAction("Print", model);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status, message = "There was an error saving the Entry" } };
    }

}
```

**tableView.cs**

```
public class tableView
    {
        public string barcode_id { get; set; }

        public string pname { get; set; }

        public int pro_price { get; set; }


        public int qty { get; set; }


        public int total_cost { get; set; }
    }


    public class ajaxModel
    {
        public List<tableView> data { get; set; }


        public int total { get; set; }

        public int pay { get; set; }

        public int balance { get; set; }




        public string orderid { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: You probably have two `sale` classes.

Comment: ya sir .sales and sales product

Comment: Yeah so pass the appropriate one, by prefixing the namespace.

Comment: i don't sir how to do the task

Comment: i attached above

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave comments so will have to leave this as an answer:

Your ID column doesn't look like it's being auto incremented, and you've not passed in an ID for it to use. You will either need to use:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

On the ID column to have it auto generate, or get the current highest id in the table and set it to that +1:

```
id = db.sales.Max(x=>x.id)+1
```

Comment: That's a runtime exception, OP has a compiler error.

Comment: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] this where have to pass sir

Comment: I couldn't get a demo of this up and running to test it just now but its a similar bug to one I've had previously which was that I wasn't passing the correct object into ".Add()", if my answer is wrong i'll remove it

Comment: As a side thought, are you sure your table migrations are up to date?

Comment: Is the "sales" class you posted, the same one that is used when defining the dbContext?